# Django unit testing if a POST request properly updates a model instance

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-testing

I'm having trouble understanding why my test keeps failing.

I have two models (only showing relevant code):

```
class Listings(models.Model):
    listing_instagram = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)
    listing_facebook = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)
    ...

class ListingsDescription(models.Model):
    listing = models.OneToOneField(Listings, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    space_description = models.TextField(max_length=1000, blank=True)
    accessibility_description = models.TextField(max_length=1000, blank=True)
    ...
```

I have a properly functioning view that processes two forms (one form per model):

```
def some_view(request, listing_id):
    listing = get_object_or_404(Listings, id=listing_id)
    listing_description = listing.listingsdescription

    if request.method == "POST":
        form_a = ListingForm(request.POST or None, instance=listing)
        form_b = ListingDescriptionForm(request.POST or None, instance=listing_description)
        if form_a.is_valid() and form_b.is_valid():
            form_a.save()
            form_b.save()
            messages.success(request, "Changes Made")
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('destination')
```

Manual testing on my browser works fine, and all fields are properly saved in the database.

However, running below test:

```
class ListingJourney(TestCase):
@classmethod
def setUpTestData(cls):
    cls.client = Client()
    # Create Listing
    cls.listing = ...

def listing_post(self):
    self.assertTrue(Listings.objects.filter(id=self.listing.id).exists())
    response = self.client.get(reverse('new_listing', kwargs={'listing_id': self.listing.id}),
                               follow=True)
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
    self.assertTemplateUsed(response, template_name='foo/listing.html')

    response = self.client.post(reverse('new_listing', kwargs={'listing_id': self.listing.id}),
                                follow=True,
                                data={
                                    'space_description': "Lorem ipsum dolor",
                                    'neighborhood_description': "Lorem ipsum dolor",
                                    'listing_instagram': "https://www.instagram.com/listing/",
                                    'listing_facebook': "https://www.facebook.com/listing/",
                                    # some more data
                                })
    self.assertRedirects(response, reverse('redirect', kwargs={'listing_id': self.listing.id}),
                         status_code=302,
                         target_status_code=200,
                         fetch_redirect_response=True)
    self.assertEqual(self.listing.listingsdescription.space_description, "Lorem ipsum dolor")
    self.assertEqual(self.listing.listing_facebook, "https://www.facebook.com/listing/")
    self.assertEqual(self.listing.listing_instagram, "https://www.instagram.com/listing/")
```

The test fails at:

```
self.assertEqual(self.listing.listing_facebook, "https://www.facebook.com/listing/")

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\tests.py", line 153, in listing_post
    self.assertEqual(self.listing.listing_facebook, "https://www.facebook.com/listing/")
AssertionError: None != 'https://www.facebook.com/listing/'
```

Meaning the Description fields were properly saved with the right text, but the social media fields are still empty. Again, manually testing, everything works fine.

printing request.POST in the view, and manually testing, also shows the name of the keys are correct:

```
<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['blabla'], 
'listing_instagram': ['https://www.instagram.com/listing/'],
'listing_facebook': ['https://www.facebook.com/listing/'],
'space_description': ['Lorem ipsum dolor'], 
'neighborhood_description': ['Lorem ipsum dolor']}>
```

Could it be that somehow the database has not finished saving the model field, before it asserts that the data is saved properly?

Help is appreciated.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to create a new listing with the same pk, which won't work.

Comment: @michjnich I'm only creating a new listing with setUpTestData, not in the actual test.
Also the POST request simply updates the existing Listing object, as you can see in the view.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by calling refresh_from_db() on the listing object after the POST request.

```
response = self.client.post(reverse('new_listing', kwargs={'listing_id': self.listing.id}),
                            follow=True,
                            data={
                                'space_description': "Lorem ipsum dolor",
                                'neighborhood_description': "Lorem ipsum dolor",
                                'listing_instagram': "https://www.instagram.com/listing/",
                                'listing_facebook': "https://www.facebook.com/listing/",
                                # some more data
                            })
self.assertRedirects(response, reverse('redirect', kwargs={'listing_id': self.listing.id}),
                     status_code=302,
                     target_status_code=200,
                     fetch_redirect_response=True)


# Added this:
self.listing.refresh_from_db()

self.assertEqual(self.listing.listingsdescription.space_description, "Lorem ipsum dolor")
self.assertEqual(self.listing.listing_facebook, "https://www.facebook.com/listing/")
self.assertEqual(self.listing.listing_instagram, "https://www.instagram.com/listing/")
```

I'm still confused as to why the test for listing.space_description was positive, but not for instagram & facebook. If someone can explain why, that would be awesome.